# What is this white bar on my door?

Tags: doors

My door has this odd looking bar with two movable parts to it and I'm trying to figure out what it is and what purpose it serves.

[image: Image of the whole door]

[image: Close up of the unusual fixture at the top of the door]

Comment: The position would seem to be for a curtain/blind/shade, but was removed from the holder/rod.

Comment: Are there any features on the outside of the door in this location? Holes? Hardware? A grille or a slot?

Comment: It looks like ventilation, but what is on the other side

Comment: the bottom picture shows ventilation holes

Comment: What parts are moveable?

Comment: @crip659 My first thought as well, but I'd expect any kind of curtain mount to be at least as wide as the window if not wider.  This one is considerably shorter, and would leave big gaps on both sides.

Answer (score 32):

It's a trickle vent. In the UK it is mandatory to have the capability to provide continuous room ventilation without having to open a window or door. The standard way of doing this is with trickle vents such as this installed in windows and doors (or their frames)

Your additional picture clearly shows two independent shutters to control the air flow. Probably a bit over-elaborate - I would suggest a single control flap is adequate.

There will almost certainly be a similar component on the outside of the door, with a grill or screen to reduce insect ingress.

Comment: One of their main purposes is to prevent the build-up of condensation inside the home, which is often a side-effect of a well-insulated building in the UK.

Comment: It certainly can occur in a well-insulated but poorly ventilated building, but in the UK the most common cause is poor insulation (causing cold spots) coupled with poor ventilation (causing high humidity)

Comment: One of my doors has a pair of flaps.  I'm not sure if it's coincidence but the trickle is more of a draught on this one compared to the ones over my windows.  Perhaps they did intend you to be able to turn it down. I think about the airflow paths and my extractors so don't open all of mine